# how to display and list json response of nearby restaurants using zomato API? I used volley to get response

Tags: android, android-volley, zomato-api

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setcontentview(r.layout.activity_main);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?&lat=27&lon=153";
    JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // response
                    Log.d("Response", response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("ERROR", "error => " + error.toString());
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user-key", "55a1d18014dd0c0dac534c02598a3368");
            params.put("Accept", "application/json");

            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
}
```

>

but i am getting all the restaurants not nearby and also please tell me how to list down the response in application.

Comment: have you tried to look in the documentation of your api to resolve issue?

Comment: What you need to do: 1. read the API documentation (basically you need to call https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/geocode), 2. Learn how to use Volley to make a call and retrieve the information. 3. Learn how to display a list of items. There are plenty of tuto all over the place. Then come back if you are really stuck.

Comment: also where is the code where you tried to add the result data to a list view or recycler view

Comment: sir, i am very new to android studio . i am not able to list down the responses.. please help me with the code.

Comment: restaurants = json.getJSONArray(restaurants);

                        for(int i = 0; i < restaurants.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject c = restaurants.getJSONObject(i);
                            
                            String name = c.getString(name);
                            String locality = c.getString(locality);
                            String city = c.getString(city);
                            String address = c.getString(address);                                                                       sir, i tried to do this to display result.

Comment: or else u can tell me the code of just to list down near by restaurants using google api. please help me with the code..

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the JSON response in json arrays and json objects respectively ,

For learning follow this link :- 
[How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

then you have to past the list to your list view  or recycler view view adapter .

for that follow this tutorial :- 
https://medium.com/@peterekeneeze/parsing-remote-json-to-recyclerview-android-1ad927e96d58